# No console output from program assembled with MASM on win32

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm

I'm running some MASM32 examples (from www.masm32.com) and I notice that the console output is blank in my command line box (program compiles, links and runs but no output.

```
    .486                                    ; create 32 bit code
    .model flat, stdcall                    ; 32 bit memory model
    option casemap :none                    ; case sensitive

    include \masm32\include\windows.inc     ; always first
    include \masm32\macros\macros.asm       ; MASM support macros
    include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
    include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
    include \masm32\include\user32.inc
    include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
    includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

    .code                       ; Tell MASM where the code starts


start:                          ; The CODE entry point to the program

    print chr$("Hey, this actually works.",13,10)
    exit


end start                       ; Tell MASM where the program ends
```

Comment: There's a `print` macro?

Comment: Dopey me, used the wrong batch file to build example (used build,bat, should have used buildc.bat).

Comment: Yes indeed there's a print macro and it's very handy.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you link a PE program for Win32, you can mark the required subsystem as either "GUI" or "Console". If you have linked this as a GUI mode program, then when you run the EXE from a command prompt Windows will not attach the console to the window you are typing into. This sounds like the symptoms you have described.

Make sure that you link your executable with the "console" subsystem flag.